# Кодировка символов в PHP под WIndows

Tags: php, кодировка

Существует ли возможность создавать файлы с именем в кодировке UTF-8? Возникла потребность создавать файлы в казахской кодировке на windows, но столкнулись с проблемой, что в php при использовании функции fopen или ей подобной создаёт очень похожие символы(далее будет видно в примере) но не то что нужно.

Пример:

```
$filename = chr(129);  - OR -  = "\x81";
fopen(".\\$filename","w"); 
file_put_contents(".\\".$filename , "test");
```

Результат - "Г`", а требуется "Ғ".

Comment: А почему вы кодируете имя файла с помощью chr, а не задаете прямо в utf-8. 129 - это вообще из расширенной части латиницы символ. А казахский как я понимаю в кирилице, ваш символ с кодом 0x492 http://unicode-table.com/ru/0492/   Правда chr работать с UTF-8 не умеет. надо извращаться что бы получить из кодов символы

Comment: >надо извращаться что бы получить из кодов символы  
Как именно нужно извратиться? Можете наводочку хотябы мне дать? 
В принципе с помощью chr символ кодируется, но не выводится корректно, да я понимаю что он работает с ASCII, но так или иначе для любого кода в chr у Винды находится символ.  
Так или иначе если задавать напрямую то получается тоже чушь вроде "Т’". Сейчас опробовал x492 Результат, как и без кодирования - "Т’".

Comment: Ну гугл мне дал такое извращение `$filename=mb_convert_encoding('&#' . (0x492) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');` оно даже выдало ваш символ в UTF-8

Comment: Нет, этот метод пробовали, но суть к одному сводится. Тем более мне  нужно отобразить это в имени файла, а не на HTML странице или в содержимом какого то текстового файла.

Comment: Нашел решение  -  https://gist.github.com/nicolas-grekas/2665437